# Office Word WebAddin loading Automatically when Word is started

Tags: office-js, office-addins

We have developed an Office Word Web AddIn (non VSTO).

We would like the task pane for this AddIn to open Automatically when the User opens Word.  We plan on using a toggle option in our UI so the user can switch this option off if they wish.  Is such a thing possible?

All our searches have pointed us to a method which relies on tagging documents first, outlined in this support document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document

We have found the method of tagging documents to have these limitations:

1. New documents will not open the AddIn automatically.
2. When a user opens a new document they are required to open the AddIn manually.  The AddIn will tag the document to open itself automatically next time but will not AutoLoad without being run once to tag the document first.
3. After the document is tagged, the user will have to SAVE the tagged document in order for the AutoLoad to work next time that document is opened.

Question 1: Is it possible to program the AddIn to open whenever Word opens rather than relying on documents to be tagged?

Question 2: If the only way to AutoLoad the AddIn is through tagging documents, are there any ways to reduce the impact of the 3 major Limitations I have outlined to ensure the AddIn gets AutoLoaded more frequently?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Bogdan

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is by design. For security reasons, it is important that the user consent to add the add-in to the document. As for workarounds, it depends on your scenario. Does the add-in need to work with any document that the user creates or opens? Or does it only need to work with certain documents made with a certain template? If it is the latter, then perhaps the first page of the template could instruct the user to add the add-in and save the file. (And delete the instruction.)

Comment: Thank you for your response.  The Add-in will need to work with any document that the user creates or opens.  This is why we are more interested in whether it's possible to make the Add-in open automatically without having anything to do with the document governing this (without having the add-in added to the document or tagging the document)